# Angularjs :How to update table after inserting record by http post?

Tags: angularjs, jsp

In my code I have to main Div which are contentOne and contentTwo . the first one is used to display the table and second one is used to fill up data and insert , after clicking on save button in contentTwo , it goes to contentOne to show the table , but this table doesnt show the new record after inserting. please help me find a way to display the updated table. thanks

```
    <div ng-hide="contentOne">
        <div  id="companyContent"  ng-controller="companyMainCtrl" >

            <section class="section">     

                <table class="table"  border="1"  cellpadding="12" rules="rows" frame="hsides" >

                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat=" x in names">
                            <td>
                                <a href="#"  id="editbutton" data-role="button" data-icon="remove" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="d" ng-click="showContent3()"><img src="images/edit1.png" alt="" style="position:relative;top:1px"></a>
                                <a href="#"  id="deletebutton" data-role="button" data-icon="remove" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="d"><img src="images/delete1.png" alt="" ></a>
                            </td>
                            <td>{{x.CMPNM}}</td>
                            <td>{{x.CMPID}}</td>
                              ...

                        </tr>


                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <img src="images/search.png" alt="SEARCH" style="position:relative;top:9px;left:96%;padding-left:1px;">       
                <input class="search" type="search" placeholder="SEARCH" name="SEARCH" size="40">

                <a href="#" id="addbutton" class="button" ng-click="showContent2()">NEW COMPANY</a> 

            </section>
        </div>
    </div>     


    <div ng-hide="contentTwo">
        <div id="newCompany"  ng-controller="newcompanyCtrl">
            <section class="section">
                <h1 style="color:rgb(24,154,177);font-family: Arial;text-shadow:2px 2px #054F5F;margin-left: 7px;">NEW COMPANY</h1>
                <label  style="position:absolute;top:105px;left:10px;font-family: Arial;font-size:16px;font-weight: bold;inline-block; width: 160px; text-align: left">NAME</label>
                <input  ng-model="companyName"   type="text" size="40" name="companyName"  class="textfieldCompany" style="left:180px;top:95px">
                <label  style="position:absolute;top:155px;left:10px;font-family: arial;font-size:16px;font-weight: bold;inline-block; width: 160px; text-align: left ">REGISTER NO</label>...

           //click on save to insert data and go to contentOne to display the table    <button type="submit" class="button1" style="position:absolute;top:405px;left:500px; padding:6px 20px" name="submitcompany" ng-click="insertCompany();
                                    showContent1()" >SAVE</button>
                <button type="button" class="button1" style="position:absolute;top:405px;left:600px" ng-model="cancelcompany" name="cancelcompany" ng-click="showContent1()" >CANCEL</button>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Script :

```
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []); 
        app.controller('mainpage', function ($scope, $http) {


            $scope.contentOne = true;
            $scope.contentTwo = true;

            $scope.showContent1 = function () {
                $scope.contentOne = false;
                $scope.contentTwo = true;
           };
            $scope.showContent2 = function () {
                $scope.contentTwo = false;
                $scope.contentOne = true;

            };


        });
        app.controller('companyMainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

            $http.get("companymain.jsp")
                    .success(function (response) {

                        $scope.names = response;


                    });
        });


        app.controller('newcompanyCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {


            $scope.insertCompany = function () {

                $http.post("newjsp.jsp?cmpNm=" + $scope.companyName + ...")
                        .success(function (response) {

                        });


            };
        });
```

Comment: use a service to share data across controllers

Comment: @charlietfl I tried that but couldnt make it works . Can you give me a simple example of that ?

Comment: may be this tutorial useful for you. http://www.angularcode.com/demo-of-a-simple-crud-restful-php-service-used-with-angularjs-and-mysql/